# Unable to convert to tensor proto : TypeError for tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto while sending a input file

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving, werkzeug

**1)** I have written a simple program using tensor flow to read a text file and wanted to deploy in a server using tensorflow serving. This is the program

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('model_version', 2, 'version number of the model.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('work_dir', '', 'Working directory.')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# define the tensorflow network and do some trains
x = tf.placeholder("string", name="x")

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
y = tf.read_file(x, name="y")


export_path_base = FLAGS.work_dir
export_path = os.path.join(tf.compat.as_bytes(export_path_base),
  tf.compat.as_bytes(str(FLAGS.model_version)))
print('Exporting trained model to', export_path)
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

tensor_info_x = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x)
tensor_info_y = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(y)

prediction_signature = (
  tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
  inputs={'input': tensor_info_x},
  outputs={'output': tensor_info_y},
  method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
  sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
  signature_def_map={
  'prediction':
  prediction_signature,
  },
  legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)

builder.save()
```

**2)** I created a protobuf of this model and made to run on the server. Now i wrote a client program to send input text file and produces output. This is a simple client file to read it

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server', 'localhost:9000', 'PredictionService host:port')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('input','','input for the model')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

def do_inference(hostport,no):

  # create connection
  host, port = hostport.split(':')
  channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
  stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

  # initialize a request
  data = no
  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name = 'modelX'
  request.model_spec.signature_name = 'prediction'

  request.inputs['input'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data))
  # predict
  result = stub.Predict(request, 5.0) # 5 seconds
  return result

def main(_):
    result = do_inference(FLAGS.server,FLAGS.input)
    print('Result is: ', result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

So when i run this code by,

> python client.py --server=172.17.0.2:9000 --input=hello.txt

it produces output

```
*Hello!*
```

**3)** Now i wrote a client file with flask framework to create REST api:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server', 'localhost:9000', 'PredictionService host:port')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

app = Flask(__name__)

class mainSessRunning():

    def __init__(self):
        host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
        channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
        self.stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

        self.request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
        self.request.model_spec.name = 'modelX'
        self.request.model_spec.signature_name = 'prediction'

    def inference(self, val_x):
        data = val_x
        self.request.inputs['input'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data))
        result = self.stub.Predict(self.request, 5.0)
        return result

run = mainSessRunning()

# Define a route for the default URL, which loads the form
@app.route('/pred', methods=['POST'])
def pred():
    request_data = request.files['file']
    result = run.inference(request_data)
    rs = json_format.MessageToJson(result)
    return jsonify({'result':rs})
```

Using postman , when i give the same input file 'hello.txt', it throws error:

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type
>   (class'werkzeug.datastructures.File.Storage') to tensor. Contents:
>   (Filestorage: u'hello.txt' ('text/plain')). Consider casting elements
>   to a supported type

I have already posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596937/failed-to-convert-object-of-type-class-werkzeug-datastructures-file-storage-t). Its working fine with normal client.py file but it is not working client.py with flask framework. I followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/util/make_tensor_proto) official document in tensorflow. And found **make_tensor_proto accepts "values" of a python scalar, a python list, a numpy ndarray, or a numpy scalar**.

So my question is how do i send this werkzeug file storage 
that it will accepted into tensor proto?  or Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

look at this url http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/

if I take a look at "def inference", the local "data" variable will hold a reference to an object of type "werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage"

when you get some file from a post[by the way of flask], this file is actually wrapped to an object "werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage" so "request.file" is not a file but an object of type "werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage" you should find a way to track the underlying file.

if you take a look at the provider url we can do this:

```
request_data = request.files['file']
request_data.save(destination_file_path)
#adapt your "inference" to get a file path instead
result = run.inference(destination_file_path)
```

in inference

```
def inference(destination_file_path):
    with open(destination_file_path) as f:
         #here handle "f" content like you want...hope that it will help you
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i need to save the file object before using it. So, the "destination_file_path" should be my local pc path or it should be my docker container Because this flask is running inside my docker container.

Comment: Why do i need to save the .txt file which is already on my local desktop? Cant we able to do it without saving the file again?

Comment: when a file is uploaded it is in a temp folder meaning it can by deleted. 'destination_file_path' is the path of a file in your docker container as flask is running in docker. You can randomly create a valid name in realtime (using some random function)